# Send more than one variable in xhr.send

Tags: php, javascript

Please help me figure out the mistake in this:

```
var username = document.getElementById("username_input").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password_input").value;
var password_confirm = document.getElementById("password_confirm").value;
xhr.open('POST', 'header/onsubmit_check.php');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("username=" + username + "&password"= + password +"&password_confirm=" + password_confirm);
```

Comment: may be some DOM error ? or `xhr` is not defined?

Comment: Where is `xhr` defined? You should use `encodeURIComponent` to encode `username`, `password`, and `password_confirm` in the `.send()` call

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Did you check the Javascript console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but maybe you forgot...

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

**Edit:** Nevermind, found it:

Change this:

```
"&password"=
```

To this:

```
"&password="
```

Comment: thanks a lot...poor mistake :)